# Firebase Auth Fail

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making a simple chat application using Firebase. But it is not adding a new user with signinwithEmailandPassword function. My code is like this

```
createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String dname = displayName.getText().toString();
            String email_str = email.getText().toString();
            String pwd = password.getText().toString();

            register_user(dname,email_str,pwd);
        }
    });

private void register_user(String dname, String email, String password){
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Inside function",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Check if you have enabled the auth type email in firebase console

Comment: Like Vikas said - have you set up auth in the console? And what is the error?

Comment: @vikasaggarwal I have enabled the auth type email in the Firebase Console, but when I run the app, it always shows "Authentication Failed" Toast

Comment: Can you provide me the logs

Comment: What is the error from your logcat?